# Why does my Ruby program takes different times to execute?

Tags: ruby

I've just started programming in Ruby.  This is my code:

```
numbers = Array (1..100)
start = Time.now

sum = numbers.inject(0) { |sum, num| sum + num }
puts "sum equals: #{sum}"

time_taken = (Time.now - start) * 1000 * 1000
puts "time taken to execute #{time_taken}"
```

Why does this code return a different execution time every time I run it?

I mean first time it was:

```
time taken to execute this: 20.593
```

second:

```
time taken to execute this: 27.184
```

third:

```
time taken to execute this: 22.516
```

Comment: Because summing up 100 integers is way too little for a proper benchmark (we are talking about nanoseconds here.). And keep in mind that this test is not the online thing running on your machine. There are plenty of background tasks running all the time that might need some CPU cycles in between too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this code return a different execution time every time I run it?

Because your computer doesn't perform the *exact same physical task* every time it runs.

Maybe the data happened to be stored in slightly more/less efficient location on the RAM? Maybe your computer was too hot/cold, so performed differently. Maybe you also have 20 StackOverflow tabs open, which was using up system resources :D

Plus, in order to get a more accurate benchmark of how quickly some code runs, you need to decrease the error margin by performing the same operation *lots* of times.

I would recommend trying the [`benchmark-ips`](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) library if you wish to get some more reliable measurements of your code's performance.